# Structured streaming - Window function - Picking the latest window always

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a structured streaming application and a window aggregation happens in the data obtained in micro batches(Based on the event time). Say I have a window of 10 minutes which gets refreshed every 5 minutes. I have got the aggregates for window 9-9.10AM, 9.05-9.15AM. But there was a delay and the application is now at 9.31 AM. Can I make sure it starts the computation for most recent window without trying to catch up on the older aggregates? (Say start at 9.20AM-9.30AM and catch up on the recent window aggregate)

```
data = data
    .withWatermark("dateField", "1 minute")
    .groupBy(col(column_x), functions.window(col("dateField"), "30 minutes", "10 minutes"), col(column_y))
    .count();

query = data
    .writeStream()
    .format("parquet")
    .option("path", xxxx)
    .option("truncate", "false")
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("checkpointLocation", xxxx)
    .start();

query.awaitTermination();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to throw away any data that comes when there is a delay? And what kind of delay are we talking about here?

Comment: I can adjust the late incoming data settings by watermark time settings. My question is "Say the job is processing the aggregates for 9 AM - 9.10AM (say 10 minute is my window time). And there comes a lag in the streaming application because of the resouces or the job failed and restarting again at 9.31 AM. It should start collecting the aggregates for 9.25 - 9.35AM or 9.20AM - 9.30 instead of computing the aggregates for 9.10AM - 9.20 AM. I am interested always in last 10 minutes data. I am not interested in old data.

Comment: I have included the code also now. In this particular code, I am creating a window of 30 minutes and it resets every 10 minutes. Waits for the late data for 1 more minute.

Comment: Maybe @zsxwing can help. If not, please post it on Spark Mailing groups